# Comparar usuários SQL Server com usuários do AD

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, sql-server, windows, ad

preciso levantar os usuários de uma instancia que não existem mais no AD para limpeza destes. Existe alguma forma de comparar os usuários do AD com os usuários de windows authentication de uma instancia SQL?

Comment: Sua pergunta me parece muito genérica e especulativa. Poderia editar ela e prover um [exemplo mínimo e verificável](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1186/como-criar-um-exemplo-m%c3%adnimo-completo-e-verific%c3%a1vel?cb=1)?

Comment: Olá Rodrigo,
vou complementar a dúvida... possuo uma instancia que possui vários logins de funcionários que não se encontram mais trabalhando na empresa, para fins de auditoria preciso revogar esses logins que não existem mais no AD mas que permanecem com seus usuários de Windows Authentication existindo na instancia, então gostaria de saber se existe uma forma de conectar no AD e fazer essa consulta\comparação sem precisar de linked server.

Answer (score 1):

Olá @rafaabell, você pode usar a stored procedure de sistema `sp_validatelogins` para exibir os logins de funcionários do Windows que não existem mais e ainda permanecem na instância do SQL Server.

```
EXEC sp_validatelogins;  
GO
```

Comment: Rodrigo muito obrigada! Era exatamente o que precisava.

Comment: Fico feliz por ter ajudado. Poderia marcar a minha resposta como útil e a sua pergunta como respondida?